# Hibernate updating bulk persistence entites

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am using hibernate  in my application to update bulk entries in list.

I have a list of employees which I get from the database by running particular criteria query. As the whole method is under transactional annotation.I want to udpate each employee in this list. So i can update the employee objects in the list, by just calling setter methods on employee objects , there is no need to call update method explicitly, as the whole list objects are under persistent context.

As of now, I am using for loop to iterate the list and updating each employee by calling setter method
like below:

```
for(Employee emp:empList){
emp.setAge(5);
emp.setAddress("ABC");
}
```

Now updating like this takes lot of time ,if I have 1000 employees in the list. how can i apply bulk operation when I am updating the fields in the persistent context by setting corresponding setter values and not by calling update method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using JPA 2.1.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Employee> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Employee.class);

Root<Employee> root = update.from(Employee.class);

//Acces properties by metamodel entity
root.set(Employee_.age, 5);
root.set(Employee_.address, "ABC");

//Add conditions where
update.where([...])

Query query = em.createQuery(update);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Be careful if you perform more write operations in the same method because the bulk operations of criteria do not respect the order of execution of the transaction.